# Flask, Python error: Showing real list on pure python, showing memory addresses in html

Tags: python-3.x, flask

When I run my code it gives me the full list of items in pure python, but when i put it in the html, it shows me the memory addresses

I have already researched the internet about this and couldn't find anything,
I hope you guys can help.
I am trying to make a card game (phase 10)

/views.py

```
def CreateDeck():
    global deck
    counter = -1
    deck = []

    # add the regular cards:
    for getl in range(1, 12):
        for klr in range(1, 5):
            counter = counter + 1
            deck.append(card())
            deck[counter].setcard(getl, klr)

    # create wilds:
    for n in range(1,9):
        counter = counter + 1
        deck.append(card())
        deck[counter].setcard(13,0)

    # create skips
    for m in range(1,5):
        counter = counter + 1
        deck.append(card())
        deck[counter].setcard(14,0)



    # shulffle the deck:
    shuffle(deck)
CreateDeck()

@app.route('/',methods = ['POST', 'GET'])
def gfhg():
    result1 = ','.join(map(str, deck))
    result1 = list(result1)
    print(list(result1))
    return render_template("player1.html", result=deck)
```

/templates/player1.html

```
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>{{ result }}</h1>
</body>

</html>
```

I expect it to show the list of "cards" on the html page. Instead i am getting this: 
Image:
https://imgur.com/0V5Qexc
Image from Pure Python:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/fB0SZ.jpg

Comment: I don't think your "Pure Python" output from `print` is correct either. Look closely at your second screenshot.. it's the same thing as the first, except it's split into individual characters.

Answer (score 0):

You should implement a `__str__()` method for you card class.

When you map a `str()` function to the each element of deck, python, under the hood, [calls a `__str__()` method of that element](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=__str__#str). But, by default, classes don't implement the `__str__()` method so python fallbacks to using a `__repr__()` method which outputs what you see -- `<class_name object at 0x0000>`